# Blocking a keyword when loading a table

Tags: php

I call the below php file which loads data from a table using curl, below, I am trimming it down to prevent showing hyperlinks and I am also replacing a string to prevent a hostname check (the last part)

```
<?php
        function curl($url){
            $headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
            $headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            $headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
            $headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
            $headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
            $headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
            $headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
            $headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";    
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return $data;    
        }    
        $a = curl('http://www.domain.com/table');
        $regex = '#<a href=[^>]+>([^<]*)</a>#';    
        $b = preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $a);
        $c = str_replace('feed_container.innerHTML+=', 'aa=', $b);
        $d = str_replace("if(location.host.indexOf('hostnamekeyword')!=-1||location.host.indexOf('hostnamekeyword')!=-1)", "if (2==3)", $c);
        print $d;
    ?>
```

What I am trying to do right now is the following:
If there is "KEYWORD2" in the a row when importing, it ignores the entire row and do not print it out. (do not show it)

Even if the code only removes the KEYWORD2, it will do the job.

Here is the complete code from domain.com/table

```
function load_dse(){var feed_container=document.getElementById('filetoload');if(location.host.indexOf('hostnamekeyword')!=-1||location.host.indexOf('hostnamekeyword')!=-1){feed_container.innerHTML='<p>error</p>';}else{var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];var css=document.createElement('link');css.type='text/css';css.rel='stylesheet';css.href='http://www.domain.com/table';head.appendChild(css);var html='<table id=\"title\" border=\"0\"><tr><td class=\"first\">&nbsp;</td><th class=\"second\">title2</th><th class=\"third\">From / Time</th></tr><tr class=\"alt\"><td class=\"first\"><img src=\"http://domain.com/image1.gif\" /></td><td class=\"second\">somthing KEYWORD2 somthing else</td><td class=\"third\"><b>from</b>: e***i</td></tr><tr><td class=\"first\"><img src=\"http://domain.com/image2.gif\" /></td><td class=\"second\">somthing KEYWORD3 something else bla bla bla</td><td class=\"third\"><b>From</b>: r***o</td></tr><tr><td class=\"first\">&nbsp;</td><td class=\"second\"><b>title3</b>: <a href=\"http://domain.com\" rel=nofollow>maintitle</a></td><td class=\"third\">07-Oct-14 03:05</td></tr><tr class=\"alt\"><td class=\"first\"><img src=\"http://domain.com/image4.gif\" /></td><td class=\"second\">somthing3 bla bla bla KEYWORD4 bla bla somehting else bla</td><td class=\"third\"><b>From</b>: r***o</td></tr><tr class=\"alt\"><td class=\"first\">&nbsp;</td><td class=\"second\"><b>Item</b>: <a href=\"http://domain/com\" rel=nofollow>maintitle2</a></td><td class=\"third\">07-Oct-14 03:05</td></tr></table>';feed_container.innerHTML=html;feed_container.innerHTML+='<p><a href="http://www.domain.com/" style="display:inline;font-size:11px;color:#808080;text-decoration:none;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">title-new<span style="color:#4374b7">Another title</span></a></p>';}}
if(typeof window.addEventListener!="undefined")
window.addEventListener("load",filetoload,false);else if(typeof window.attachEvent!="undefined"){window.attachEvent("filetoload",lfiletoload);}
else{if(window.onload!=null){var oldOnload=window.onload;window.onload=function(e){oldOnload(e);window[filetoload]();};}
else
window.onload=filetoload;}
```

Please help, I tried different methods, but no matter what I do, it would not work.

Comment: Could you give an example input and the desired output?

Comment: have you considered using an HTML parser?

Comment: Just added the sample code we are searching in domain.com/table above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$e = preg_replace('#>* KEYWORD2#i', '', $d);
print $d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is helpful:

```
$e = preg_replace('#<tr.*?>.*KEYWORD2.*?<\/tr>#i', '', $d);
print $e;
```

This will remove the table rows that contain KEYWORD2.
Guess this is what you need.

You can check the results here: http://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/9
With all the explanations and tests. Very nice site!

Comment: Thank you, the code is going on the right direction, now, the issue is that, wherever it finds the KEYWORD2, it trims the rest of the table. (basically the table stops where the keywork2 deteted,

Comment: I just added the contains of the domain.com/table file in question above

Comment: @Schwann Can you add a example content of the whole table, so I can see how the regexp is working in practice? One row is not really enough , cause even as it is now this row is removed. :)

Comment: @Schwann Check the new version - just tested it and should be OK!

Comment: I used the new one but I have the same issue, when I isolate the code in regex101.com, it shows that the above code should work, but when i actually use it in my website (which is loading it inside a php page) it still stops showing the remaining of the data right after the KEYWORD2, I posted the entire code in question, Thank you again

Comment: @Schwann What we need is content of the table. Everything starting with `<table>` and ending with `</table>`. You can also do the tests on the site regex101.com

Comment: what I added to the question is the entire table and it does include everything from <table>to</table>, I am still trying buy changing the tr to td but still no luck

Comment: @Schwann This regexp is working like  charm! :) Check the result here: http://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/10 Note that only the row with KEYWORD2 is replaced. My advise is to make simple test with PHP console script. Manually assign the content to variable and do the replacement and print it. This way you will be sure that the PHP & PCRE version that you are using support this regexp.

Comment: you are correct, the code works by itself, but I think I found the issue, replacing the tr or td will change the structure and this table is working by an identifier (first, second and third) removing one will stop the entire table to show properly, so they only way to fix it is by removing just the keyword and replacing it with "" or "somthing else", do you know how to do this?

Comment: I figured changing the code to     $e = preg_replace('#>* KEYWORD2#i', '', $d);
print $e;    will fix the issue, but the only thing I cannot find out is if we have more than one KEYWORD2, the code stops on the first one, how to ask it to continue and do the same for all the KEYWORD2s only